# I want to find the average value in column D

Tags: excel, vba, average

I want to find the average in column D of the data against which they correspond in column F of the last 10. Not knowing how many rows will be Mid (T) or Hi (T). So far I have done this:

```
 Dim c As Range
 Dim theRow As Long
 
    Range("D11").Select

    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
 
    For Each c In Selection.Rows
       c.Style = "Good"
       theRow = c.Row
    
        
        If (Range("D" & theRow).Value > 80) And (Range("D" & theRow).Value < 85) Then
            Range("F" & theRow).Value = "Hi(T)"
        End If
        
        If (Range("D" & theRow).Value > 20) And (Range("D" & theRow).Value < 79) Then
            Range("F" & theRow).Value = "Mid(T)"
        End If
        
        If (Range("D" & theRow).Value > -42) And (Range("D" & theRow).Value < -39) Then
            Range("F" & theRow).Value = "Lo(T)"
        End If
        
    Next
```

and here I want put one cycle For, but I can't figure out how

in picture you see the data, and I have automatic average last 10 data from Mid(T) in column "D"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MBAgh.png)

Comment: This sounds like Excel VBA? Please tag correctly. Thank you

Comment: Why VBA? You can do this with worksheet functions, filtering in various ways depending on your version of Excel.

Answer (score 0):

To count the last 10 rows of each category it's easier to start from the bottom and move up.
NB: If there are not 10 lines which meet the criteria then no average will be printed. This behaviour could be modified.

```
Dim c As Range
Dim theRow As Long
Dim hCount, mCount, lCount as int
Dim hSum, mSum, lSum as long
 
Range("D11").Select

Range(Selection,Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
theRow = Selection.Count + 12

    While lLine > o do
       theRow = theRow - 1
       c.Style = "Good"
       theRow = c.Row
    
        
        If (Range("D" & theRow).Value > 80) And (Range("D" & theRow).Value < 85) Then
            Range("F" & theRow).Value = "Hi(T)"
            hCount = hCount +1
            hSum = hSum + 1
            If hCount = 10 then
                Range("E" & (theRow + 9)).value = hSum / hCount
            End if
        End If
        
        If (Range("D" & theRow).Value > 20) And (Range("D" & theRow).Value < 79) Then
            Range("F" & theRow).Value = "Mid(T)"
            mCount = mCount +1
            mSum = mSum + 1
            If mCount = 10 then
                Range("E" & (theRow + 9)).value = mSum / mCount
            End if
        End If
        
        If (Range("D" & theRow).Value > -42) And (Range("D" & theRow).Value < -39) Then
            Range("F" & theRow).Value = "Lo(T)"
            lCount = lCount +1
            lSum = lSum + 1
            If lCount = 10 then
                Range("E" & (theRow + 9)).value = lSum / lCount
            End if
        End If
        
    Loop
```

Comment: You can see picture, and I have automatic average last 10 data from Mid(T) in column "D" After that next data for Hi(T) last 10. But I do'not know how many rows we have.